# Navigation between two pages in symfony

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations, twig

I'd like to navigate between 2 templates in a Symfony project. 
It works well in local, but not in OVH.

*`defaultController.php`*

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function mainPage()
{
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Matches /carole/*
 *
 * @Route("/carole", name="blog_carole")
 */
public function carole()
{
    return $this->render('default/carole.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'DefaultController',
    ]);
}
```

*`annotations.yaml`*

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

*`index.html.twig`*

```
<div id="title">Site perso</div>
<div id="caroleWebsite">
    <a href="{{ path('blog_carole') }}">Site Internet de Carole</a>
</div>
```

OVH returns a 404 error.

Comment: From the code examples provided it's not possible to diagnose the error cause. The code looks ok. I'd look at the settings with the host provider OVH.

Comment: Could you show us the URL on the first page and the URL after getting the 404? That could help with figuring out the issue. The issue could be that you are using on your production server URL such as mywebsite.com/myproject/ (the first page) and mywebsite.com/myproject/carole (second page). The path function might be redirecting you to mywebsite.com/carole, giving you a 404.

Comment: Actually, the main page is mywebsite.com and the other is on mywebsite.com/carole